# I want pull to data from customer table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
sno  name cd1 cd2 cd3 cd4 cd5 cd6 cd7 cd8
1    ram  RL  RL  RL   CD VF   RT  EE   N
2    SAM  RT  LT  RT   LT  RR  RT       N
3    VAN  LT  LT  RR   VV  FF  GG       N
4    HH   LT  RT  RR   VV  GG  HH       RT
```

Now my question is, I want to pull RT ,LT in cd1 to cd8 at any of the line. But if RT present in the one column LT should not come and if LT is there RT should not come in the result.

Expected result

```
sno name cd1 cd2 cd3 cd4 cd5 cd6 cd7 cd8 
  1 ram  RL  RL  RL  CD  VF  RT  EE  N 
  3 VAN  LT  LT  RR  VV  FF  GG      N
```

Comment: You need to show us your expected output.  It is not clear from your description.

Comment: Can you also add how the output table should look like?

Comment: sno  name cd1 cd2 cd3 cd4 cd5 cd6 cd7 cd8
1    ram  RL  RL  RL   CD VF   RT  EE   N
3    VAN  LT  LT  RR   VV  FF  GG       N

Comment: Example you posted suggests that there's nothing to be done. The first row already contains RT (so you can't enter LT). The second row contains **duplicates** (2 x RT, 2 x LT) - what about those? Row 3 contains 2 x LT, row 4 already has LT and RT. So, rows 2 and 4 violate "constraint" you described. Does it mean that you should remove some of those values, or what?

Comment: I want to pull only 1 and 3rd line that's Criteria that gave to me

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to include further information such as expected output. Code and sample data are too hard to read as comments.

Comment: Hm, why did I read "put" and not "pull"? Should get a new pair of glasses, apparently. Thank you, @APC.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be this; the duplication is nasty but that's the price of a horrible data model.

```
select * from customers
where 'RT' in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
and 'LT' not in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
union all
select * from customers
where 'LT' in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
and 'RT' not in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
/
```

The first sub-query returns rows where one of the code columns has a value `'RT'` and none have a value of `'LT'`, and the second sub-query returns the complementary set.

This would be the simplest approach except that you have nulls in `cd7` and alas `not in` does not play nice with null values. So this query only returns the row `sno = 1`. We need to handle that:

```
with cte as (
    select sno, 
           name, 
           nvl(cd1, 'n/a') as cd1, 
           nvl(cd2, 'n/a') as cd2, 
           nvl(cd3, 'n/a') as cd3, 
           nvl(cd4, 'n/a') as cd4, 
           nvl(cd5, 'n/a') as cd5, 
           nvl(cd6, 'n/a') as cd6, 
           nvl(cd7, 'n/a') as cd7, 
           nvl(cd8, 'n/a') as cd8
    from customers
)
select * from cte
where 'RT' in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
and 'LT' not in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
union all
select * from cte
where 'LT' in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
and 'RT' not in (cd1 ,cd2 ,cd3 ,cd4 ,cd5 ,cd6 ,cd7 ,cd8)
/
```

This query returns rows `sno = 1` and  `sno = 3`, as required. [LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f10a6q8v0n9m8yhq4bm0wbhb9)

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

```
select * 
  from customer 
  where case when 'RT' in (cd1, cd2, cd3, cd4, cd5, cd6, cd7, cd8) then 1 else 0 end
      + case when 'LT' in (cd1, cd2, cd3, cd4, cd5, cd6, cd7, cd8) then 1 else 0 end = 1
```

`Unpivot` version:

```
select * 
  from customer 
  join (select sno 
          from customer
          unpivot (val for col in (CD1, CD2, CD3, CD4, CD5, CD6, CD7, CD8))
          group by sno 
          having count(distinct(case val when 'RT' then 1 when 'LT' then 2 end)) = 1)
  using (sno)
```

<sup>**[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b72a/2)** for both queries.</sup>